# "git: error while loading shared libraries: libcharset.so.1 No such file or directory" when trying to use git on Chromebook/Crostini

Tags: linux, debian, git, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I am trying to use git from the command line on my chromebook for dev work. I installed git from apt-get (and then git-all after this issue first appeared to see if that would solve it but it didn't).

If I try running any git command I get:

```
git: error while loading shared libraries: libcharset.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I could only find [this bug report about the issue](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew/issues/3305) where users are saying that libcharset is part of libiconv, so I tried installing that but it doesn't exist in apt, another search led me to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898826/why-is-there-no-libiconv-package-in-ubuntu) where a user says that `libcharset` is part of `libc6` so I tried installing that but it said I already had the newest version. I also tried to install `libc6-dev` but that was already the newest version too.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is there another way to get git working on the command line on crostini?

Comment: Did you run `apt update` before installing? This refreshes the package metadata so apt knows which packages are available.  If not do so and then repeat the install command.

Comment: Or run `apt install -f` to install missing dependencies.

Comment: Yes I did run apt update, thanks for the comment though.

Comment: I just checked Crostini on my Chromebook.  Git is installed by default.  If you haven't customized yours much, start fresh by removing and readding Linux in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just check ld so path configuration

`$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`

If the path of libcharset.so.1 isn't included in that configuration list, then just add the path into /etc/ld.so.conf and update path config

```bsh
$ sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf
$ sudo ldconfig -v
```

And try git again!